# Adding Wildcards to Forge Server later

Tags: laravel, nginx, wildcard-subdomain, laravel-forge

When I created a server using Laravel Forge, I didn't provision it with wildcards at inception. I would like to add wildcards now, while the server is running. Can this be done?